# Creating diagonal matrix from one half of the matrix

Tags: excel, matrix

In excel sheet, I have computed one half of my diagonal matrix. Now, I would like to transpose the upper half so I can mirror it do the lower halfof the matrix. On the diagonal I have zeros. How can I achieve this? When I select the cell range of my upper half of the matrix and transpose it to the lower part it just does not work. 
My matrix should be 388X388 cells so You can imagine that I would like to avoid copying and transpozing each row individually.
PS: I can not work with VBA. 
Thank you

EDIT:

I have tried the OFFET function according to the answer below, but I am still getting this message. What it says is basicly, that there is a problem with that formula, but it does not specify what is the source of the problem. In comments below I am attaching also a link to office support page, where you can find the exact translation of this alert message. I have also tried to use classic cell addressing A1, but with same result.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the OFFSET function. This is a reference function that allows you to specify a cell that is a certain number of rows and columns from a starting cell. Combine this with ROW() and COLUMN() functions to get the value from later columns as you drag the formula down rows and later rows as you drag the formula across columns.

The simplest case is assuming you have data starting from A1:

[image: 1]

You can then put this formula into cell A2: `=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-1)`

When you fill it into the remaining cells, it will transpose your matrix.

[image: 2]

If your matrix doesn't start in A1, you'll just need to change the amount you subtract from COLUMN() and from ROW() to allow for where it actually starts.

You can also easily fill the formula into all blank spaces:

1. Enter the formula into A2
2. Select the entire matrix
3. Press `Ctrl+g`, then select Special, then select Blanks and click OK
4. Hold `Ctrl` and click on A2
5. Press `F2`
6. Press `Ctrl+Enter`

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to apply this on the exact example as you showed, but after typing the formula into A2 Excel throws error. I am assuming that it requires some parameters in COLUMN and ROW function. What Am I doing wrong please?

Comment: No they don't require parameters. They return the column and row numbers of the current cell. What error are you getting? Can you please paste a screenshot, including the formula?

Comment: I am getting exactly this message.  My sheet looks exactly like yours (I have used even same numbers :) ). I copied the formula you wrote here and pasted it into A2. After hitting ENTER, I get this message: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-avoid-broken-formulas-8309381d-33e8-42f6-b889-84ef6df1d586

Comment: Oh, are you using R1C1 notation? If so, that's worth mentioning! Try this: =OFFSET(R1C1,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-1)

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question. I have added a screenshot. The message is in Slovak language, but it is basicly the same message you saw in the link from my previous comment. Thank you

Comment: Oh, your version of Excel may have different function names to match your language. Use Formulas > Insert Function then use the "Lookup & Reference" category to find your equivalents. This page may also help you get started: http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-polish.html

Answer (score 1):

I am using the solution of @Michael with a more flexible way. 
 The problem is,  if the matrix is not starting from $A$1, it does not work. 
 Lets say the top left cell is $G$22. Then the modified equation is:

=OFFSET($G$22,COLUMN()-COLUMN($G$22),ROW()-ROW($G$22))

Answer (score -1):

Refer to [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60126&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), it worked for me using this corrected offset code. My array starts at C3 and I am copying bottom part to top part. So the formula for cell D3 (should return C4 value) is

```
=OFFSET(C3,1,0,1,1).
```

Hope it works for you.