# Mirror colored cells diagonally in Excel? (for charting purposes)

Tags: excel, mirror, mirroring

I'm trying mirror colored cells diagonally in Excel. For example, I'm trying to create a chart showing muscles that are complement or conflict each other if you work them out on the same day in a weightlifting schedule. I've completed half of the chart here: https://gyazo.com/12baa17122c38dcfc6cddcff42b73059

[image]

As you can see, it would be redundant to fill out the bottom half of the chart manually. I only filled up the cell B3 "Triceps:Biceps" on the bottom half as an example. I just want to mirror the colors of the top half diagonal to the bottom half diagonal.

Is it possible to do this? Thanks

Comment: If you already have all possibly pairs then it's redundant to fill out the bottom part of the chart *at all*, and I would suggest you leave it blank (maybe hide the border for those cells.

Comment: @ashleedawg That is a good point. Do you know how to go about hiding the border of those cells then? or just hiding them in general? I don't know how to make an irregular selection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474677/creating-diagonal-matrix-from-
one-half-of-the-matrix This did it for me. :)